# I have too many DNS servers configured

Tags: networking, router, dns, dhcp

The OS is Win 8.1.

I have my laptop connecting to my wireless router, and I have told the router to issue out DNS via the DHCP lease.  The laptop is configured to use the information. The router is configured to only issue two DNS server addresses from open dns, but the laptop reports

```
Networking Dns Servers: 
10.197.100.1
10.197.100.2
10.197.100.3
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
208.67.222.222
208.67.220.220
```

I have no idea where the laptop is getting these additional IPs as DNS. Please advise.

Comment: What operating system is your laptop using?

Comment: Assuming that your laptop is running a Windows OS, DNS servers are configured per each network interface. Can you post the output of `ipconfig/all`?

Comment: Windows 8.1 is my OS.

Comment: The ipconfig /all was too long for the comments... but I only see two (opendns) servers listed.  The solution did not work.

Comment: What command, control pannel, or tool are you using that shows this output?  I've not seen this before. `ipconfig /all` from cmd or powershell will tell you what the real DNS servers in use are.

Comment: I actually discovered that I had "ghost" adapters with DNS entries configured.  The solution I had to use was going into the registry and clearing these entries by hand.  I'm not sure if there is a more intuitive way to do this, but, the issue is solved for me now.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you configured both [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/) and [Google's DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/) at some point.

1. Click `Start` and type `View Network Connections`
2. Right click your network adapter, probably called "Local Area Connection", select Properties
3. Double click "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)
4. Click the "Advanced" button
5. Select the DNS tab
6. Remove the unwanted DNS servers
7. Click "OK" three times
8. Click `Start` again and type CMD and hit enter
9. Type `ipconfig /release` and hit Enter
10. Type `ipconfig /renew` and hit Enter

That should fix your extra DNS entries.

Comment: I have two interfaces listed, the ethernet and the wireless.  Both have "obtain ip" and "dns" automatically enabled.  Ethernet cable is unused.

Comment: What Keltari means is you need to go to the advanced section (not just the "obtain automatically"). You may have some historic DNS addresses registered that need to be cleared.

Comment: Ok, I tried again.  Nothing there to remove.